# why my first pipe operation didn't remove newline character?

Tags: pipe, command-substitution, tr, head

My `nextermCensus.lis` contains newline character and I am only interested in the first line, I'd like to remove newline character. but it doesn't work.  so I have to use second method to remove it.  `$(echo $census_day | tr -d '\n')` works as I expected.  But I really like to do it in one line.

```
census_day=`head -1 /dr4/home/operbat/batches/nextermCensus.lis | tr -d '\n'`
census_day=$(echo $census_day | tr -d '\n')
```

Comment: You don't need any of those... just `census_day=$(head -n1 /blah/blah/census.lis)`; the newline is added by `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

The command:

```
bla=`head -1 filename`
```

already removes the newline. The `echo`command appends the newline again.

Try:

`echo "$bla\c"`

(if you are using a POSIX compliant echo) and you will see that there is no newline in `$bla`.

Comment: Note that POSIX doesn't mandate support for `\c`, only Unix does (XSI option is the SUS/POSIX spec). The behaviour of `echo "$bla\c"` and `echo -n "$bla"` are unspecified per POSIX. Anyway, using `echo` here is wrong as we don't know what `$bla` main contain. So, `printf %s "$bla"` (or `%b` if you want to expand echo-like sequences in it).

Comment: You may take into account that XSI means X-OPEN compatible. Given the fact that the POSIX standard since many years is written and maintained by The Open Group and the fact that since the early 1990s all governmental sites required OpenGroup "extensions", we can safely assume that all POSIX systems of interest are XSI compliant as well.

Comment: The scope of this site is Unix-like operating systems including Unix-like Free software distributions built for Linux (generally around a GNU core) (the _Linux_ in _Unix and Linux_). Those distributions follow POSIX roughly,  XSI sometimes.  Same for many BSDs. And they actually give their modern credibility to POSIX and the OpenGroup.  90% of the questions here are about GNU, not Unix. Strict XSI compliant represent a small fraction of the systems in scope for this site, and probably of the current focus of the OpenGroup I'd say.

Comment: So what is your problem here? I just tested bash and it supports `echo "bla\c"`

Comment: My _problem_ is that POSIX doesn't specify that `echo "$bla\c"` output the content of `$bla` without a trailing newline. Bash can be configured so that `\c` causes `echo` to stop ouputting (though it doesn't by default), but `echo "$bla\c"` would still not output the content of `$bla` without the extra newline if `$bla` happened to contain backslash characters.

Comment: Well if bash may statically ignore \c, this looks like a big problem. The traditional UNIX solution is to switch to the BSD method only when /usr/ucb/ in before /usr/bin in the PATH. The BSD method however can be seen as a non-clean method in special as \c was in use on UNIX since the mid 1970s (see nroff/troff).

Answer (score 1):

By default, `echo` will add a trailing newline to any string or variable it is told to print. Your first command works perfectly, there is no newline there, command substitution (`` `...` `` or its modern equivalent `$(...)`) strips every trailing newline character. It is only added if you attempt to `echo` the variable.

So, for example, given this file:

```
$ cat foo.txt
a
b
c
```

I could save the 1st line, excluding the newline, simply by using `head`:

```
$ census_day=`head -n 1 foo.txt`
```

Now, if you were to `echo` it, you would see a newline but if you were to use `printf`, or `echo -n` (for `echo`s that support it) you wouldn't:

```
$ printf %s "$census_day" | od -tc
0000000   a
0000001
```